# See time in task changes 2 days (or more) ago

Tags: tfs

When I look at a task on the board I can see that I've made field changes 2 days ago. Is there anyway to see more info about the changes? For example I want to see what time I did the change. All I can see is what change I did, by clicking the small arrow, but I also want to know the time.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should see the exact date time when move the mouse over the text:
[image]